# Why can child modules use private items of ancestor modules, but not the other way?

Tags: oop, rust

Why can't items in a parent module use private items inside child modules, but items in child modules can use the private items in their ancestor modules?

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-03-paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree.html

Comment: For my own education, how do you foresee the answer to this question helping you? That may help guide answers to provide useful information. Would you accept "because someone said so" as the answer?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you showed the research you've already performed before asking this question. Rust has been developed in the open for a long time (if not since its inception), so it's generally likely that any interesting decisions can be found with a little legwork. We wouldn't want to bore you with details you already know about.

Comment: From the page you linked: "The reason is that child modules wrap and hide their implementation details, but the child modules can see the context in which they’re defined."

Comment: Basically, you can see private items from the _inside_ of a module, but not from the _outside_. Submodules are on the inside of their parents.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is a design choice.

In Rust all items are private by default, they only become public if explicitly defined with pub. Private items can only be accessed from the same module or from modules that are under this same module. (modules that are child of the module where the item was defined).

So yes, a module can access private items not only from its immediate parent module but also from the module that is the parent of its parent, and so on. However a module cannot access private items from a child module, it only can access public items from its child module.